# Correct way to query multiple many-to-one relationships in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I currently have three tables: formulas, videos, and articles. The rows in the formulas table have a many-to-one relationship with the videos and articles.

My API is required to output this relation in the form:

```
formulas: {
  // some number of formulas
}
videos: {
  // videos belonging to the formulas
}
articles: {
  // articles belonging to the formulas
}
```

I've come up with two different ways to do a query that will get me the information I need, but I fear that due to my inexperience with SQL neither are good methods.

Method one seems like terrible practice to me, but it does it all in one query. However, it also requires me to do some formatting with the results:

```
SELECT formulas.formula_id,
       formulas.formula,
       formulas.name,
       array_agg(videos.link) AS video_links,
       array_agg(videos.name) AS video_names,
       array_agg(articles.link) AS article_links,
       array_agg(articles.name) AS article_names
FROM formulas LIMIT 200
LEFT JOIN videos on videos.formula_id=formulas.formula_id
LEFT JOIN articles on articles.formula_id=formulas.formula_id
GROUP BY formulas.formula_id;
```

Method two seems a little more normal. It requires multiple queries, which isn't the end of the world, but from what I've read it's better to do things in just one query:

```
SELECT * FROM formulas LIMIT 200;

SELECT * FROM videos WHERE formula_id IN (SELECT formula_id FROM formulas LIMIT 200);

SELECT * FROM articles WHERE formula_id IN (SELECT formula_id FROM formulas LIMIT 200);
```

Method one seems atrocious to me, and method two seems fragmented into too many queries.

Could someone demonstrate a better/more correct way of querying multiple many-to-one relationships?

Comment: Unrelated but: a `LIMIT` clause _without_ an order by doesn't make sense because the values returned by that might differ between each execution. Each of your three statements _might_ return a different set of `formula_id`s. Also: the `LIMIT` is applied to the whole query, not to a single table. `from formulas LIMIT 200` is invalid.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for letting me know! If you can't tell I've been working with SQL for a very short amount of time so I'm very appreciative of this advice.

Comment: Both would work; depending on your table size and structure, each will have different performance issues. Neither is, IMHO, "atrocious;" profile them and see which performs better under the expected conditions.

Comment: Another thing, you _probably_ want `string_agg` instead of the `array_agg` in the first query. But this depends highly on your programming language and what you need to do with the result.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name other than the `LIMIT` needing an `ORDER BY` and the `string_agg` vs `array_agg` is there really no better way to do these queries? I just want to make sure I start off learning/using SQL properly.

Comment: It all depends on what you want to do with the results. There is no single "best" way to do this kind of things. If it's for a report, I'd go for solution one. If this is for an interactive GUI where the user first selects one formula and then you need to display the related rows for that, the second approach is probably better. Or a combination: one query to get the formulas and one to get all related vidoes and articles. Or something completely different. Unless you tell us what you need to do with the results this is nearly impossible to answer.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank you for all the feedback! It's more of an get all the information at once type application so I guess I'll go with option one. Could you please leave your comments as an answer so I can accept it? You've been very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on what you want to do with the results. There is no single "best" way to do this kind of things. If it's for a report, I'd go for solution one. If this is for an interactive GUI where the user first selects one formula and then you need to display the related rows for that, the second approach is probably better. Or a combination: one query to get the formulas and one to get all related vidoes and articles. Or something completely different. Unless you tell us what you need to do with the results this is nearly impossible to answer.